# Why is My App Crashing everytime I implement this Logic?

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

> There are multiple cardView in the App, and Click on each Card a new Intent is launched. Also before launching the Intent I am passing a puExtra along.

```
  final String label = holder.text_label.getText().toString().trim();

    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (position == 0 && label.equalsIgnoreCase("Alt. English")) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShowPDFActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("AltE","AltE");
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
    });
```

> And in my another Activity, I have created an Array of Titles, where i Have stored all the possible values which are received in this Activity.

```
 String[] title = {
            "AltE",
            "Alt.English2013"
    };
```

> Now I am running a for Loop to see what value is received and accordingly perform the functions.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    for (int i = 0; i <= title.length; i++) {
        Log.e("Length ", String.valueOf(title.length));

        a1 = intent.getStringExtra(title[i]);

        if (a1.equalsIgnoreCase("AltE")) {

            String pdf = "https://www.researchgate.net/STUDIES.pdf";
            webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + pdf);

            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    // do your stuff here
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "In Else", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

> But the App crashes with this Message :

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

> What Am i Doing Wrong and how can this be Fixed ?

Answer (score 1):

First reverse:
from

```
if (a1.equalsIgnoreCase("AltE")) {
```

to

```
   if ("AltE".equalsIgnoreCase(a1)) {
```

because "AltE" will not be equal to null
will make it stop crashing.

Also the reason for your crash is that getStringExtra returns default null
and you are checking *for each* title, rather than just one.
and so for the  `"Alt.English2013"` you don't have a value, according to your story.